# Can I call hooks conditionally in React if the conditions won't change across the component's lifetime?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

```
function Component({ condition }) {
  const initialCondition = useMemo(() => condition, [])
  const state = initialCondition ? useHook1() : useHook2()
  return <h1>{state}</h1>
}
```

If we know the value `initialCondition` will not change it throughout the life of the component, can it be used as a conditional statement specifying which hook to use?

Through experience, there were no problems, there are not many problems

Comment: This code violates the [rules of hooks](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning)

Comment: You cannot conditionally call a hook, it breaks the [Rules of Hooks](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning), if you know the value of `initialCondition` won't change then why pass it? Alternatively pass the value of `initialCondition` to a hook and let it work out it's behaviour from there

Comment: Every time that component runs, it needs to run the same hooks in the same order.  Perhaps you need two components.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Harrison and James: not sure why you say this violates the rules of hooks. This code **does** run the same hooks in the same order in every render!

Comment: @Harrison ping!

Comment: I'm not sure @Bergi.  "Do not call Hooks inside conditions or loops."  I get that it doesn't change.  Maybe eslint would complain but the code would work.  Does it break the rules?  Yes.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the question comments, there are "[Rules of Hooks](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning)" which in particular state:

> Do not call Hooks inside conditions or loops.

But as also noted, the actual hard technical requirement behind that rule, is that React needs that whenever a Component re-renders, all its called Hooks must be exactly the same, in the exact same order. Kind of a fingerprint.

The Rule just enforces this requirement, in a manner that is easy to follow for developers and linting tools.

While you can break the Rule, as long as you ensure somehow that the exact same Hooks are run in the exact same order for a given Component instance, then indeed, React will not crash.

But you can easily accommodate your use case to that Rule, combining the suggestions in the question comments:

```
function Component({ condition }) {
  // No conditional Hook
  return <h1>
    { condition // The condition is used to select Components, not Hooks
      // If the condition changes, it destroys the child Component instance and creates a new one,
      // instead of calling a different Hook, which would break React
      ? <ComponentWithHook1 /> // No condition passed
      : <ComponentWithHook2 />
    }
  </h1>
}

function ComponentWithHook1() {
  const state = useHook1() // Hook at the root level of the Component body
  return <>{state}</>
}

function ComponentWithHook2() {
  const state = useHook2()
  return <>{state}</>
}
```

Comment: Personally I think an HOC taking the hook function to call would be more appropriate. Then you wouldn't need to duplicate the definition of `Component` with one thing swapped out: `function withHook(useHook) { return function Component() { const state = useHook(); ... }; }`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yes it is absolutely preferable to factorize! I preferred keeping it simple here, since it was not the point. We could even use a dynamic component variable, provided that props are the same (same for potential arguments of the Hooks).